# Let R = $\{1, a\}$, S = $2^R$ and $T = 2^S$. List all the elements of S and T

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having a little difficulty understanding how to approach this question.
When S = $2^R$ and T = $2^S$, would that mean that the elements of S = $\{2^1,\space 2^a\}$ and T = $\{2^2,\space 2^{2a}\}$?

By that understanding, would $|S| = 2$, $|T| = 2$, $|S \cup T| = 4$, and $|S \cap T| = \emptyset$?

I am completely new to these topics and I am slowly learning. Your patience is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reference is to the power set.

So $S$ is the set of subsets.  Here we get $S=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{\alpha\},R\}$.

Now $|T|=2^4=16$.

Can you list the elements?

Comment: Could you elaborate further, Please?

Comment: We're considering subsets here.   That's the key.   So in the case of $T$, it's actually the set of subsets of a set of subsets.   I'll give some of the $16$ elements, and you try to get the rest.   $T$ contains,  for instance,  $\{\{1\}\},\{\{\alpha\}\},\{\{1\},R\},\{\{\alpha\}, R\}$.  So there's double set brackets.   There are $12$ more elements.   And always remember the empty set and the whole set, $S$.

Comment: Oh, okay. I see. Would the elements be: [∅, {∅}, {{1}}, {{a}}, {R}, {∅, {1}}, {∅, {a}}, {∅, {R}}. {{1}, {a}}, {{1}, {R}}, {{a}, {R}}, {∅, {1}, {a}}, {∅, {1}, {R}}, {{a}, ∅, {R}}, S] ?

Comment: @MikeHong, that is very close, but you are missing one three-element subsets of $S$.

Comment: Alright, sweet. I got it. Thank you all very much!